# Python 3: End of File error with no message

Tags: python, eoferror

I'm having some trouble figure out how to create an EOFError without printing something after it.

This is the section of the program I'm having trouble with:

```
def main():
  try:

    k = float(input("Number? "))

    newton(k)
    print("The approximate square root of", k,"is:",newton(k))
    print("The error is:",(newton(k))-(math.sqrt(k)))

  except EOFError:

    print("End of File")
```

I'm trying to make this so that it doesn't print anything after the user presses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>. The program should be killed right after <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.

I've trying doing `print("")` but that creates an extra space.

Thanks in advance

Comment: does `pass` work?

Comment: use `pass`. it should work fine.

Answer (score 2):

```
def main():
    try:

        k = float(input("Number? "))

        newton(k)
        print("The approximate square root of", k,"is:",newton(k))
        print("The error is:",(newton(k))-(math.sqrt(k)))

    except EOFError:

        pass
```

As a separate note, I noticed that you are using 2 spaces in your code indentation. It's a good practice to use 4 spaces instead.

Comment: You're right in general about the 4 spaces standard. But I often compress things to 2-space indents for posting on SO and similar sites, just so things fit on small screens. As long as you're 100% consistent, it's 4 keystrokes in emacs to go back and forth. (And as a side benefit, it's a good test to force myself and my colleagues to be 100% consistent, which is far more important to me than which stanard we've chosen to be consistent with…)